# Return value from python script via CGI

Tags: python, cgi, raspberry-pi2

I work on a raspberry Pi. I did a small html page with 2 buttons calling executables via CGI and doing things. I would like to add a temperature display on the same page.

I have a small python script that reads the temperature of a sensor and I can successfully display it on console or via direct CGI (typing the url, the only thing displayed is the temperature). I would like to see the temperature directly on my html page, and be able to refresh the value by clicking a button.

I can't find any answer that might help me returning a value from the python script and displaying it in a textbox or something. Do you have any track for me to follow ?

Comment: A simple way is to make your CGI re-write the whole HTML page with the updated data.

Comment: normally you are better off with using [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) instead of CGI - also frameworks like [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/) or [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) make things easier

Answer (score 0):

You can write out a complete html page with CGI

A simple CGI script would be

```
temp=100
print("Content-Type: text/html")    # HTML is following
print()                             # blank line, end of headers
print("<!doctype html>")
print("<html><head><title>Example</title></head><body>")
print("<p>Temperature is:",temp)
print("</p>")
peint('<a href="#">Reload<a>')
print("</body></html>")
```

you can also use javascript in a page to (re)load the value with [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) - there are examples on the page (only replace the php-script with your python-cgi)